# MongoDB - How to group documents and conditionally push each item to array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of `phrases` with the following structure:

- phrase - string
- phraseLength (the length of the phrase string)
- author - string

I would like to group phrases by author. And for each author, the maximum length of all that author's phrases shouldn't exceed 200 characters.

In other words, I am trying to figure out how to create an aggregate query that will:

- loop through each phrase
- If current author's total running phrases length is less than 200 characters, then push it to the author's phrases array

So for example with the following documents (I added incorrect phrase length for each document for ease of understanding):

```
[
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 1',
        phraseLength: 50,
        author: 'Author 1',
    },
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 1',
        phraseLength: 150,
        author: 'Author 1',
    },
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 1',
        phraseLength: 10,
        author: 'Author 1',
    },
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 2',
        phraseLength: 20,
        author: 'Author 2',
    },
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 2  of author 2',
        phraseLength: 180,
        author: 'Author 2',
    },
    {
        phrase: 'This is phrase 3  of author 2',
        phraseLength: 50,
        author: 'Author 2',
    },
]
```

This is the desired output:

```
[
    {
        _id: 'Author 1',
        phrases: [
            {
                phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 1',
                phraseLength: 50,
                author: 'Author 1',
            },
            {
                phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 1',
                phraseLength: 150,
                author: 'Author 1',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'Author 2',
        phrases: [
            {
                phrase: 'This is phrase 1 of author 2',
                phraseLength: 20,
                author: 'Author 2',
            },
            {
                phrase: 'This is phrase 2  of author 2',
                phraseLength: 180,
                author: 'Author 2',
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I know how to group all phrases by author like this:

```js
db.phrases.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$author',
            phrases: {
                $push: { phrase: '$phrase', phraseLength: '$phraseLength', author: '$author' }
            }
        }
    },
])
```

And I have tried the following query to accomplish the desired outcome but it didn't work.

```js
db.phrases.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$author",
            runningTotalPhraseLength: { $sum: '$phraseLength' },
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $lte: [{ $size: '$runningTotalPhraseLength' }, 200]
                },
                then: {
                    phrases: {
                        $push: { phrase: '$phrase', phraseLength: '$phraseLength', author: '$author' }
                    }
                },
                else: {},
            },
        }
    },
])
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to define the conditional accumulate push logic in the `$group` stage.

But you need another `$set` stage with `$reduce` operator.

1. `$group`
2. `$set` - Create a `temp` field.

   2.1. `$reduce` - Iterate each element in `phrases` array and return a new object.

   2.1.1. `input` - `phrases` array.

   2.1.2. `initialValue` - Initialize an object with `length` and `phrases` fields.

   2.1.3. `in` -

   2.1.3.1. `$cond` - Compare if the accumulated `value.length` plus the `length` for current iterate object is lesser or equal to 200.

   If true, then set the object with `length`: `$$value.length + $$this.length` and `phrases` with add the iterated phrase object to the accumulated `$$value.phrases`.

   Else, remain the same value for the accumulated `$$value`.
3. `$set` - Replace `phrases` array with `temp.phrases`.
4. `$unset` - Remove `temp` field.

```
db.phrases.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      phrases: {
        $push: {
          phrase: "$phrase",
          phraseLength: "$phraseLength",
          author: "$author"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      temp: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$phrases",
          initialValue: {
            length: 0,
            phrases: []
          },
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $lte: [
                  {
                    $sum: [
                      "$$this.phraseLength",
                      "$$value.length"
                    ]
                  },
                  200
                ]
              },
              then: {
                length: {
                  $sum: [
                    "$$this.phraseLength",
                    "$$value.length"
                  ]
                },
                phrases: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ],
                    "$$value.phrases"
                  ]
                }
              },
              else: "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      phrases: "$temp.phrases"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "temp"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WwNossHFZR1)

Answer (score 1):

Using [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) to compute cumulative length and then conditional grouping,

```
db.phrases.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$author",
      sortBy: {null: 1},
      output: {
        "cumuLength": {
          $sum: "$phraseLength",
          window: {
            documents: ["unbounded","current"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      phrases: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {$lte: ["$cumuLength",200]},
            {
              phrase: "$phrase",
              phraseLength: "$phraseLength",
              author: "$author"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fk7--fsMWD6)